# Connecting the dots on the given diagram

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

What is the best or easiest way to connect the dots on the given diagram. I would like to connect the dots to form a rectangle. The dots are initially blue color.

[image]

Comment: It'd be nice if you wrote how you approached the problem and at which part you need help.

Comment: Please specify a programming language. What about the (noisy) points at the extreme left? Do you want to connect also them? Do you want some procedure to handle such kind of noise? Or you can just remove them with some preprocessing, and give an image where all white points are meaningful? Hint: use `convexHull`

Comment: [How to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  and [How to connect the dots](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/254223/looking-for-an-algorithm-to-connect-dots-shortest-route)

Comment: Thanks @Miki .. i just needed a technique to start things.. now i have convexHull ..cheers

Comment: Gift Wrapping Algorithm maybe? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gift_wrapping_algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create **tetragon** (shape with 4 vertixes) instead of **rectangle** (shape with 4 vertixes and all angles equal to 90 degrees) - i. e. connect points that human can simply classify as lines, the simplest way is creating array with points coordinates, and then applying [cv::approxPolyDP](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#approxpolydp) or [cv::convexHull](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#convexhull).

Answer (score 0):

You did not specified what kind of shapes you want to get, convex or concave.
Miki mentioned convex hull algorithm.

You can also search for Concave Hull algorithm.
Here is one of possible sources in C++:
https://bitbucket.org/vostreltsov/concave-hull/src

Here is also some theory: http://www.it.uu.se/edu/course/homepage/projektTDB/ht13/project10/Project-10-report.pdf

Or if you search for rectangles only then take a look at cv::minAreaRect method from OpenCV.