# OpenCV connecting dots

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I want to find the outer most corner of the dots in this image to use for a geometric transform. I intended to use hough to get the lines on the edge of the sheet and find where they intersect but it's turns out that is not possible because of the lack of lines. I would appreciate help finding alternate solutions to connect these dots.

[image]

Comment: What have you done about it?

Comment: I have added the image now

Comment: If you are able to find dots, just find the corner points by using their location, then draw lines using those points.

Comment: Please tell me that you haven't just created a new dummy user just to re-ask [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33855402/connecting-the-dots-on-the-given-diagram) question.

Comment: No but that's probably someone in my class!

Comment: Ok then :D. the answer to that question has some great pointers. You can start from there.

Comment: If you can remove the noise on the left part of the image, convexHull or minAreaRect will already do a decent job.

Comment: Ok thank you I hadn't come across that post!