# Min and max value of Point2f vector

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

I want to find four corners of a rectangle out of a vector of Point2f points.

These points will be the max and min x values with their respective values and the other two corners will be the max y values with their respective y values.

So far I found the max and mins for x and y. I am trying to figure out how to reunite these max values with their other value so i have four x,y points. Is this possible?

Edit: The rectangle is at an angle with respect to the picture view.

This is my code as it stands and is working well:

```
vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints;
blob_detector->detect(backproj_dilate, keypoints);

vector<Point2f> XY;
for (size_t i=0; i<keypoints.size(); i++){ 
    XY.push_back(keypoints[i].pt);

}

float X, Y;
float maxX= 0;
float minX = 10000;
float maxY= 0;
float minY = 10000;
for(size_t i=0; i<keypoints.size(); i++){
    X = XY[i].x;
    Y = XY[i].y;
    if( X > maxX){
        maxX = X;
    }
    if( X < minX){
        minX = X;
    }
    if( Y > maxY){
        maxY = Y;
    }
    if( Y < minY){
        minY = Y;
    }

}
```

Comment: do you try to solve http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33938487/opencv-connecting-dots ? if so, please try what @Miki suggested.

Comment: Whilst I was researching those I came across a simplBlobDetector which I thought was great because it gave me the coordinates of each dot. That's how i am here now. Do you think what I am attempting to do is not possible?

Comment: if you post your complete code i can show how to do what you want.

Comment: See the OpenCV sample minarea.cpp .

Comment: I'm not at my laptop right now but I'll have a look and get back to you. Thank you for the help.

Comment: As the question is stated, all three answers below are valid (well, Jefery's is the only one complete, in my opinion). You could just use [convert](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/d29/classcv_1_1KeyPoint.html#acfcc8e0dd1a634a7583686e18d372237&gsc.tab=0) and `boundingRect` for that, however. So please ask a new  (more clear) question, and accept one of these answers. Or better, just try what we have already suggested to you in your previous question. BTW, `simpleBlobDetector` is an overkill for this task.

Comment: I cannot use the bounding rectangle because I want to find the corners of the rectangle to perform a geometric transformation and the vertices are quite far off from the corner points. I will ask my question again more clearly.

Comment: It's still unclear what you're asking. Please post a couple of images with actual and expected results.

Comment: Hi Miki I have re asked the question here. Hopefully that is more clear. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33984685/max-and-min-vertices-in-a-square

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than your current structures, which are like:

```
struct vector2 { float x, y; };
struct key_point { vector2 pt; };
```

you could have a rectangle structure that holds all four corners:

```
struct rect {
    vector2 top_left;
    vector2 top_right;
    vector2 bottom_left;
    vector2 bottom_right;
};
```

and then you can populate them all with:

```
std::vector<key_point> key_points;
auto x_comparator = [](auto const& a, auto const& b) { return a.pt.x < b.pt.x; };
auto y_comparator = [](auto const& a, auto const& b) { return a.pt.x < b.pt.x; };

float max_x = boost::max_element(key_points, x_comparator)->pt.x;
float min_x = boost::min_element(key_points, x_comparator)->pt.x;
float max_y = boost::max_element(key_points, y_comparator)->pt.y;
float min_y = boost::min_element(key_points, y_comparator)->pt.y;
auto rectangle = rect{
    {min_x, min_y},
    {max_x, min_y},
    {min_x, max_y},
    {max_x, max_y}
};
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8110455c9b0c3628)

Comment: Hi sorry I should have been more explicit in my question. The rectangle is at an angle so The corresponding y value to maxX value is not the max or min y value.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following two functions in CV, depending upon whether the bounding box is rotated or not:

1) [boundingRect](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gacb413ddce8e48ff3ca61ed7cf626a366)

2) [minAreaRect](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga3d476a3417130ae5154aea421ca7ead9)

The subsequent x,y returned in the rect/roated rect array are the xmin and ymin. and the other parameters can be used to get xmax, ymax.

Answer (score 0):

Well now you have

```
(maxX, maxY)
(minX, minY)
```

You already know it's a rectangle, so the other two points are

```
(maxX, minY)
(minX, maxY)

       minX          maxX    
   0|---|--------------|--
    |
 minY (minX, minY)  (maxX, minY)
    |
    |
    |
    |
    |
 maxY (minX,maxY)   (maxX,maxY)
    |
```

Comment: Hi sorry I should have been more explicit in my question. The rectangle is at an angle so The corresponding y value to maxX value is not the max or min y value.

Answer (score 0):

Well you've got 4 points :

```
P1 = { XMin, YMin }
P2 = { XMax, YMin }
P3 = { XMin, YMax }
P4 = { XMax, YMax }

P1 ---- P2
|        |
P3 ---- P4
```

You can put that in a data structure

```
struct Rectangle
{
    float UpLeft[2];
    float UpRight[2];
    float DownLeft[2];
    float DownRight[2];
};
```

(I supposed here that Y = 0 is at the top and X = 0 is on the left)

Comment: Hi sorry I should have been more explicit in my question. The rectangle is at an angle so The corresponding y value to maxX value is not the max or min y value.